# Proper way to log exceptions happening before logger service has initialized in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

We are using Serilog connected to Graylog to manage our logging and that works great for runtime issues, but the problem we have is that the service gets initialized in `Startup.cs` and is not available in `Program.cs`, where we might be getting an error (IIS shows 500 returned from Kestrel, but nothing in our logs).

What's the recommended way to handle this - there seems to be an option for stdout in the ASP Core module's `web.config`, but not sure if that will provide the information I need. The other option seems to be adding a separate logging code in `Program.cs`, but that feels like an unnecessary workaround, as in there is probably a better default way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting up all logging in `Program.cs` is possible, and recommended with Serilog. From the [Serilog.AspNetCore README](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore):

```
public class Program
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateLogger();

        try
        {
            Log.Information("Starting web host");
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
            return 1;
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseSerilog()
            .Build();
}
```

Comment: This seems to be it - not sure why I've missed it. Thanks a lot!